# Knockout value binding not updating when jquery off/on used to remove handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a situation where i have a dropdown list bound using knockout:

```
<select id="RoleGroups" class="tableDropDown" data-bind="options: userGroups, 
                                                         optionsText: 'group_nm',
                                                         optionsValue: 'group_cd',
                                                         value: selectedRoleGroup">
</select>
```

I have a change handler set on the dropdown:

```
self.roleGroupChanged = function() {
       //do stuff                    
    return true;
};
```

When i update the observable array of the dropdown i reset the current selectedRoleGroup observable to a default.  I want to prevent the roleGroupChanged handler from firing in this case so i do the following:

```
$('.tableDropDown').off('change');

//do stuff...set the dropdown value

$('#RoleGroups').on('change', self.roleGroupChanged);
```

The problem i am running into is that the observable value selectedRoleGroup is now not being updated when the dropdown changes.  I can use jquery to get the current value but that defeats the purpose of using knockout.  If i remove the code that uses jquery's off and on methods everything works as expected but the handler fires as a result which is not what i want.  Looking for ideas what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that binding/unbinding the `change` event is the right approach to solve your problem.  If I understand your requirement correctly, you simply want to set a default value to `selectedRoleGroup`, if the contents of the observable array changes?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the jQuery events directly, you could tap into the `change` event in your data-binding. If you use a simple true/false observable for tracking when you are updating your observable array, you can use `preventDefault()` on the event args for the change event. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/3q7f3/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out so thought i would post....apparently just doing a .off('change') removes more than just my roleGroupChanged handler.  If i do a .off('change', self.roleGroupChanged) or if i had namespaced my handler when i ran .on('change.mystuff', self.roleGroupChanged) and followed it up with a .off('change.mystuff') or .off('.mystuff') everything works as expected.